# Overlay part of the matrix on top of another

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have two numpy arrays - basically numpy representations of SimpleCV images. One of the matrices contains mostly zero entries, except a few that are not. I would like to copy over those non-zero entries to the other matrix. I can easily do it with simple `for` loops, but I would like to do it with numpy for clarity and performance reasons. After reading the docs it seems like masked arrays are the way to go, but I am having trouble figuring out how to tell numpy to ONLY copy over the non-masked entries. A dummy example:

```
x = np.array([1,2,31,32,4,0,3,0,0,0])
y = np.ma.masked_where(x == 0, x)
z = np.array([99] * len(x))

z[:] = y
```

I expect `y` to update only the non-masked entries in `z`, but instead a normal copy gets executed. Am I on the right track here, or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: Don't create `z` like that... If you want a one-liner, do `z = np.zeros_like(x) + 99`, if you don't mind two `z = np.empty_like(a); z.fill(99)`. In the new numpy 1.8 you can also do `z = np.full_like(a, 99)`.

Comment: @Jaime Or don't create `z` at all, since any of the solutions can just broadcast with simply `z = 99`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the 3 argument form of `np.where` for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,2,31,32,4,0,3,0,0,0])
>>> z = np.array([99] * len(x))
>>> y = np.where(x != 0, x, z)
>>> y
array([ 1,  2, 31, 32,  4, 99,  3, 99, 99, 99])
```

Comment: I know you just copied it from the OP, but the `z = ...` line is unnecessary, since `where` will broadcast:  `y = np.where(x!=0, x, 99)`

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Instead of using `masked_where`, you can find the values in `x` that aren't 0 using the `!=` operator for `ndarrays`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,2,31,32,4,0,3,0,0,0])
>>> y = x != 0 # create a boolean array of indices i where x[i] != 0
>>> y
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> z = np.array([99] * len(x))
>>> z
array([99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99])
>>> z[y] = x[y]
>>> z
array([ 1,  2, 31, 32,  4, 99,  3, 99, 99, 99])
```